# What is a supported streaming datasource to persist result?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to use the new streamed writing feature with spark 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT. which output datasource are actually supported to persist the results? 
I was able to display the  output on console with something like this:

```
Dataset<Event> testData = sqlContext
    .readStream()
    .schema(schema)
    .format("json")
    .load("s3://......")
    .as(encoder);

Dataset<Row> result = testData.filter("eventType = 'playerLoad'")
    .groupBy(col("country"), window(col("timestamp"), "10 minutes"))
    .agg(sum("startupTime").alias("tot"));

result.writeStream()  
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination();
```

but if I try to change .format("console") to "json" or "jdbc" I have the message: Data source xxx does not support streamed writing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (as of Jul 9, 2016) there are four available streaming sinks:

- `ConsoleSink` for `console` format.
- `FileStreamSink` for `parquet` format.
- `ForeachSink` used for `foreach` operator.
- `MemorySink` as `memory`.

You can create your own streaming format implementing [StreamSinkProvider](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/interfaces.scala#L137).